# Python 3.1.1 for OS X FSEvents

Tags: macos, python-3.x, fsevents

1. Am working on file / folder event capturing of OS X 10.5 and 10.6 versions. My application is developed using Python 3.1.1. Donno whether **FSEvents** are supported by **Python 3.1.1**.

   2. If FSEvents are not supported by Python 3.x, is there any other way to do this using Python 3.x?

regards,
Kingsley Reuben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not, there aren't that many libraries for Python 3.x yet. It might be easy to adapt some of the Python 2 libraries, though (http://bitbucket.org/nicdumz/fsevents/, for example).

Comment: Hi,

I hope this could help me. Gotto port the script to Python 3 and try out.

Kings

Answer (score 0):

[MacFSEvents](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MacFSEvents) supports Python 3 as of [version 0.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MacFSEvents#id3).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Will try out. Getting answer for a post after 3 years is really awesome!